# Returning the BLOB value from a database

Tags: oracle, byte, blob, wav, clob

I'm currently working on an windows from application that reads .wav files into a byte array  and stores this byte array to a certain Oracle database.
I'm storing the bytes as BLOB and and conversion seems to be working since there's no corruption.

My problem is I have no idea on how to read the bytes back from the database.
I need to be able to read the bytes from the database and convert them back into their original .wav format.

I tried to do this with CLOB but the files got corrupted after uploading them to the database.

Im using Visual Studio 2012 and Oracle 10g.

Comment: You really need a blob, not a clob which is suitable for text. Are you using odp.net?

Comment: no im not using odp.net and yes i know i need a blob since clob version gives me a courrupted file, the problem is i cant get a parameter return from blob like i can from clob :(

Comment: Since you mentioned VS, chances are that you are on .net I which case odp.net might be an option for you. Here's an article on how to read blobs with odp.net: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-nov/o65odpnet-085139.html

Comment: thanks this looks useful, ill let you know if i can get a result

Comment: hello sorry for the late reply but this solution doesnt work for me, its just returning System.Byte[] which doesnt convert back to anything.

Comment: yes, a blob is collection of bytes. what did you expect?

Comment: the value of those bytes?

Answer (score 0):

I have no Idea how it works in Visual Studio 2012. But you can use a PL/SQL procedure to do sth. like that. Have a look at this link:
[Downloading Documents from the Custom Table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13363/up_dn_files.htm#CIHDDJGF)